# Which method is better for mysql optimization

Tags: mysql, sql

Lets say I want to store numeric data with upto 10 decimal points. Which approach is better in terms of speed and storage?
1. Define all fileds as decimal(20,10) or
2. Multiply all numbers by 10^10 and store them in a bigint column

Thanks in advance

Comment: Bigint is always the fastest choice, but it was only important in 20th century when CPUs were 1000 times slower than today. Today almost nobody needs these microoptimizations. If this is a quest from textbook, maybe you should find a newer edition. ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, consider that our database will have over 16 million records and will update every 2 minutes. There will be a process over all those records every 3 minutes too. Should we still ignore this microoptimization for such a usage?

Answer (score 0):

You should store data values in the data type most appropriate to what the data represents.  In this case, if you want 10 decimal digits after the decimal place, then use `decimal(20, 10)` or something similar.

There is no reason to play games with data types.  Micro-optimizations such as fiddling with types is rarely needed.

The only consideration is whether these are "real" numbers or just codes.  If they are codes, then you might consider a string type.  For instance, US zip codes look like numbers, but they are really codes.  Hints are that leading zeros are important and that arithmetic on them is not meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

The first obviou problem with using `BIGINT` in this way is that only actually supports number positive integers up to about `10^19` (in signed mode), and even fewer than this in unsigned mode.

This aside, it is generally not good practice to use an integer to represent a decimal.  One main reason is that you may not be able to control what decimal/whole components are being entered.  That is, for example, if someone entered say 30 digits, do you interpret this as 20 digits to the left of, and 10 digits to the right of, the decimal point?  Or, maybe this number actually represents 20 places of precision to the right of the decimal point.  I suggest just using `DECIMAL`, which can handle all of this issues for you.

Comment: Your feedback is much appreciated, but consider to be 16 million records with a process over all those fields every 3 minutes.